# Mysql_query won't send to a database

Tags: php, mysql, send

I'm creating a registration page for a website. When i submit the form, the data is not sent to the database. Anyone know why this is occurring? The following code is from the script called register.php  I dont see why it wont send to my mysql database. Last night i had an error "phpMyAdmin - Error Cannot start session without errors, please check errors given in your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly."
But now its working. Could it be from that?

```
<?php
echo "<h1>Register</h1>";

$submit = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'submit');
//form data
$fullname = strip_tags (filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'fullname'));
$username = strtolower(strip_tags (filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username')));
$password = strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password'));
$repeatpassword = strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'repeatpassword'));
$date = date("Y-m-d");


if ($submit)
{
//open database
$connect=mysql_connect("localhost","root","mypasswordwouldgohere");
mysql_select_db("phplogin");

$namecheck = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$username'" );
$count = mysql_num_rows($namecheck);

if($count!=0)
{
die("Username already taken, please choose another");
}

//check for existence
if($fullname&&$username&&$password&&$repeatpassword)
{
    if ($password==$repeatpassword)
    {
    //check char length of username and fullname
        if (strlen($username)>25||strlen($fullname)>25)
        {
        echo "Length of username or full name is too long!";
        }
        else
        {
        //check password length 
            if (strlen ($password)>25 || strlen ($password)<6)
            {
            echo "Password must be between 6 and 25 characters";
            }
            else
            {
            $password = md5($password);
            //register user 


            $queryreg = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES           ('','$fullname','$username','$password','$date',)");
            die ("You have been registered! <a href='index.php'>Return  to the login page</a>");



            }   
        }   
    }
    else echo "Your passwords do not match";
}
else echo "Please fill in <b>all</b> fields!";

}


?>
<p>
<html>

<form action='register.php' method='POST'>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
        Your full name:
        </td>
        <td>
        <input type='text' name='fullname' value='<?php echo $fullname;?>'>
        </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
        choose a username:
        </td>
        <td>
        <input type='text' name='username' value='<?php echo $username;?>'>
        </td>

    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td>
        Choose a password:
        </td> 
        <td>
        <input type='password' name='password'>
        </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
        Repeat your password:
        </td> 
        <td>
        <input type='password' name='repeatpassword'>
        </td>
    </tr>

<table>
<p>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Register'>

</form>
```

Comment: Hint #1: use `mysql_error()` to find out the problems, e.g.,  `mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());` Hint #2: Switch to [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). The `mysql_` functions are antiquated and should no longer be used.

Comment: did you "check errors given in your PHP and/or webserver log file" as advised?

Comment: use mysql_error() on every query to make sure it works, and tell you what the problem is if it doesn't.

Comment: What are the datatypes for the users's table?

Comment: 1 id - int 2 name - varchar 3 username - varchar 4 password - varchar 5 date - date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have SQL Syntax error `"INSERT INTO users VALUES           ('','$fullname','$username','$password','$date',)"` here. Remove last ',' in your query.